# Kinetic energy in work energy theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics

What is the difference between kinetic energy and change in kinetic energy? Wouldn't the change in kinetic energy give a result which is a kinetic energy and if the change in kinetic energy can be negative then the resultant KE can also be negative which is not possible. Isn't it?

Comment: Change in kinetic energy is just final K.E. minus initial k. E. That's all there is to it.

Comment: If $T_2-T_1 = \Delta T < 0 $ then is just $T_2 < T_1$. This doesn't mean any of the kinetic energies is negative.

Comment: "Wouldn't the change in kinetic energy give a result which is a kinetic energy?" This means little to me without a context in which it makes sense. Can you supply one?

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 apples today. Tomorrow you only have 2 apples. The difference is -3 apples.

It makes no sense to talk about having a negative amount of apples. In the same way, kinetic energy is an amount of "something" that you have. An amount of motion energy - when you have none, then you aren't moving, so a negative amount doesn't mean anything.

That doesn't mean that the amount you have can't increase or decrease. A decrease would be written as  a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Change in any magnitude is  **"final value minus initial value**.

$$\Delta X = X_{final} - X_{initial}$$

For kinetic energy:

$$\Delta E_k = E_{k, final} -E_{k, initial}$$

So, for example, if you are $1kg$ and you are initially moving at $3 m/s$, your initial kinetic energy is:

$$E_{k, initial} = ½\cdot 1 kg \cdot (3 m/s)^2 = ½\cdot 9 J = 4,5 J $$

If your final speed is $2m/s$, your final kientic energy will be

$$E_{k, final} = ½\cdot 1 kg \cdot (2 m/s)^2 = ½\cdot 4 J = 2 J $$

Therefore, the change in kinetic energy is "final value minus initial value":

$$\Delta E_k = 4,5 J - 2J = 2,5 J$$

---

Now, some conceptual issues.

> Wouldn't the change in kinetic energy give a result which is a kinetic energy?

No, that's not true. The fact that both have the same units does not mean they are the same thing.

Both torque and energy, for example, share the same units: $N\cdot m$ (we call it *joules* in case of energy). However, they are totally different magnitudes.

The same magnitude must have the same units. All energies must have energy units.

The reverse is not neccesarily true.

A difference ine quantity is a substraction, so it will have the same units. However, the meaning is different.

For example, change in kinetic energy is also measured in joules, but it is not an energy, is the **change in energy**.

Velocity might be clearer: you slowed down from 3m/s to 2m/s. The difference is "minus 1 joule".

This is the difference of velocities. However, there is no particle moving at that speed. That's not a real speed: nothing in your problem is moving with 1m/s. It is not another speed, it's just the substraction of two values. Same units, different meaning.